# How to force center grid-element to linebreak

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-grid

I am using the `Bootstrap` grid system for styling. What I want to achieve is the following (the illustration on the top is meant to be for Desktop size, the one on the bottom for mobile view):

[current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W4Ot.png)

The items are located in a div with the classes `row` and `container`.

```
<div class="container row">
 <div class="col-md-2 col-6">
    div1
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-9 col-12">
    div 2
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-1 col-6">
    div 3
 </div>
</div>
```

The css `.container` class:

```
.container {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: space-between;
     height: 100%;
}
```

Currently, I am getting something like this when resizing to mobile:
[image: current state]

How can I achieve the layout shown in the first image?

Comment: Send a link as an example.

Comment: No, please don't post a link.  Post a snippet of the code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: For a proper answer, you need to provide a [mcve], and it should be **within** the question, not as an external link (or both).

Comment: I added the html code and rewrote the problem specification, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Getting the second element below the first and third might not be possible. Maybe you should try some other library as Masonry. https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thanks ReSedano, that was exactly my problem, I could solve it with using the Bootstrap order classes.